# Lie derivative on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative

This is an exercise left for homework, taken from the textbook which we follow in class, Lee's book ''Introduction to Smooth Manifolds'' Second Edition.

Definition: $D_vW(p)=\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}|_{t=0} W_{p+tv}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{t}(W_{p+tv}-W_p)$ (*)

Suppose $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $W$ is a smooth vector field on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that the directional derivative $D_vW(p)$ defined by (*) is equal to $(L_VW)_p$, where $V$ is the vector field $V=v^i\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}$ with constant coefficients in standard coordinates.

Any thoughts? Am i supposed to use the theorem which states $L_VW=[V,W]$, or is there a simpler way to show this equality? Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Hint: the flow of $V$ is $\theta_t(p)=p+tv$.

Comment: Aha! So i guess, even if in the general case of the Lie derivative we need a different approach for the numerator to make sense, in $\mathbb{R}^n$ a 'simple' curve starting at $p$ with initial velocity $v$ should suffice. By choosing a line we get a directional derivative. So i just use the usual equation describing the Lie derivative as a limit and it's just a walk in the park from there on, right?

Comment: Yes. $\phantom{}$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function defined by $f(t)=x+tv$, $W(x+tv)=W(f(x)), {d\over{dt}}W(x+tv)={d\over{dt}}W(f(x))=dW({d\over{dt}}f(t))=dW(V(x))$.

This the directional derivative, but not the Lie derivative.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative

Comment: Pretty straightforward. No need to mess with flows then?

Comment: It's not a typo, a theorem in the book is stated exactly like this, regarding vector fields on a manifold $M$, not $\mathbb{R}^n$. Haven't seen the $D$ and 'dot' notation before, could be the same thing in my case. Anyway, thanks for your insight!

Comment: D is just the differential